# SQL Query Required for below scenario

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch the emp_id from the below table (table1) which have joined (joining_date) department dept1 and dept2 on same date.

```
emp_id|| department||     joining_date
1     || dept3     ||     01/01/2014
1     || dept2     ||     01/01/2015
1     || dept1     ||     01/01/2015
2     || dept1     ||     01/01/2015
2     || dept2     ||     01/03/2015
3     || dept1     ||     01/02/2015
3     || dept2     ||     01/02/2015
3     || dept3     ||     01/02/2015
4     || dept1     ||     01/01/2014
4     || dept2     ||     01/01/2014
5     || dept1     ||     01/01/2014
5     || dept2     ||     01/01/2015
5     || dept3     ||     01/01/2016
6     || dept1     ||     01/01/2014
6     || dept2     ||     01/01/2014
```

So, i should get 1,3,4 & 6 as a result.

Comment: use distinct with emp_id

Answer (score 1):

Use INNER JOIN on the same table.

```
SELECT `first`.* FROM table1 AS first
INNER JOIN table1 AS `second`
        ON `first`.emp_id = `second`.emp_id 
                AND `second`.department = "dept2" 
                AND `second`.joining_date = `first`.joining_date
WHERE first.department = "dept1"
```

Example for the dept2, you have to add dept3

Answer (score -1):

You can use self-join to get result

```
select distinct d1.emp_id 
from   dept1 d1, 
       dept2 d2 
where  d1.department = 'dept1' 
and    d2.department = 'dept2' 
and    d1.joining_date = d2.joining_date;
```